# Change modeline background when in normal evil mode?

Tags: evil, faces

how do I change the background of current line when in (evil) normal mode?

I used it in Vim to be able to tell when I am in normal mode or not.

(I am using the terminal app and I prefer to keep the cursor a rectangle so I need a different visual aid.)

Comment: Are you asking about the [*mode line*](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Format.html), or about the line the cursor is on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand right, this should help get you started

```
(setq original-background (face-attribute 'mode-line :background))
(setq normal-state-background "#ff0000")
(add-hook 'evil-normal-state-entry-hook
          (lambda ()
            (set-face-attribute 'mode-line nil :background normal-state-background)))
(add-hook 'evil-normal-state-exit-hook
          (lambda ()
            (set-face-attribute 'mode-line nil :background original-background)))
```